# Storing classes inherited of a class template in a C++ Vector

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, vector, interface

I want to store classes derived of a class template `MyClassTemplate` in a vector.

Unfortunately, in C++ it is not possible to define a vector of `MyClassTemplate` without specifying its parameters (something like `std::vector<MyClassTemplate<?,?>> myVector;`).

But there is the possible solution to define a not templated interface (class with only pure virtual functions) as type of the items in the vector. 
This interface is inherited by the class template. In my case the class template has just members which are using template parameters, so it seems that just an empty interface would be a suitable item type for my Vector.

Is there another (better) solution for this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by `std::vector<MyClassTemplate<?,?>> myVector;` not being possible? Minimal example, please

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I'm sure to have `MyClassTemplate<A,B>` and `MyClassTemplate<C,D>` in one vector.

Comment: Why do you want to store elements of unrelated types in a container? How woud you apply any operation to them if you don't know their types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What I understand from your question:**

- You have a template class `MyClassTemplate<class X, class Y>`;
- You already know that each template instantiation (e.g `MyClassTemplate<A,B>` and `MyClassTemplate<U,V>`) is a different unrelated type;
- You'd nevertheless like to put such unrelated type in the same vector, to be able to use the common interface and use the vector elements in a polymorphic way.

**How to solve this ?**

First, you could define a common non template ancestor:

```
class MyCommonAncestor {
public:  
    virtual void common_operation1()=0;
    virtual ~MyCommonAncestor() {}
}; 

template <class X, class Y> 
class MyTemplateClass : public MyCommonAncestor {
    X myx; 
    Y myY; 
public:  
    void common_operation1() override; 
    X operation2(const Y& y); 
};
```

Unfortunately, doing so doesn't really allow you to use a `vector<MyCommonAncestor>` because such a vector would hold `MyCommonAncestor` objects only (which can't be created because they have a pure virtual function here) and if they could be created, they would [slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the derived objects that you'd put in (i.e. they risk to loose `myX` and `myY`).

You could however create a vector of pointers. I show here a simplified example for illustration, using raw pointers; but in reality you'd better use `shared_ptr`:

```
vector<MyCommonAncestor*> myVector; 
myVector.push_back(new MyTemplateClass<A,B>); 
myVector.push_back(new MyTemplateClass<U,V>);
```

You could then iterate through the elements and apply the common functions, according to the `MyCommonAncestor`'s interface.

**Challenges**

A challenge occurs when you want to call a function that depends on the template parameters (example `operation2()`).  Obviously, these can't be included in the common ancestor, as they depend on template paramters which are not yet defined.

Possible workarounds:

- avoid these, and call such functions only indirectly via common operations (which can be overridden in the template)
- use in the common interfaces abstract types for parameters.  Pass these by pointer or by reference.  Later, for A and B or U and V, make sure that these are derived from the intended abstract types.

**[Online demo (with smart pointers)](https://ideone.com/Xl2sKr)**

Comment: @isanae you are completly right ! Generally that's what I do, but I omitted it here as the question was rather conceptual.  But I've edited the typos and added a link to a working online demo

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct S { void f(); };

std::vector<S> v;
```

where `v` can contain any instantiation from `S<>`. You won't be able to. `S<>` is a class template. You can see it as a *type generator*. Each type you generate from `S<>` is distinct: `S<int>` and `S<float>` are as different as `int` and `float` themselves.

If you want to have a container of any `S<>`, you need to play the polymorphic card:

```
struct base
{
    virtual ~base() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

template <class T>
struct S : base
{
    void f() override
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<base>> v;
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<S<int>>());
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<S<float>>());
    v.push_back(std::make_unique<S<char>>());

    for (auto&& s : v)
        s->f();
}
```

Output:

```
int
float
char
```